# Ignoring 0 score tasks using Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have 2 methods and I need to count average values including tasks that a student did not try  to solve (with 0 score). Everything works until 0 appears. And I stuck with this. What is my problem?

1. totalScores - Return map of persons to their total scores (as average);
2. averageTotalScore - Return average result of all persons (be sure to consider all tasks of the course and not just those that were completed by a particular student).

I mean that if a student has a some number (in my case it is 4) of laboratory works, some of which the student passed (in my case is 3) for some points, and some (1) not (they should become 0 points), and then the `totalScore` should count average values including tasks that a Student did not try to solve (with 0 score). But it counts without 0 points. And `averageTotalScore` should calculate the average values for each lab, including all Students (in my case is 3) and those who did not try to solve (with 0 points).

```
For example:
Student  | Lab1 | Lab2 | Lab3 | Lab4 | Total | Mark |
Eva Bee  |    0 |   83 |   89 |   59 | 57.75 |    F |
John Show|   61 |   92 |   67 |    0 | 55.00 |    F |
Phoebe Li|   75 |   94 |    0 |   52 | 55.25 |    F |
Average  |45.33 |89.67 |52.00 |37.00 | 56.00 |    F |

Expected: 57.75, Actual: 77.00


public class CourseResult {
    private final Person person;
    private final Map<String, Integer> taskResults;
    public CourseResult(final Person person, final Map<String, Integer> taskResults) {
        this.person = person;
        this.taskResults = taskResults;
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public Map<String, Integer> getTaskResults() {
        return taskResults;
    }
}
```

```
     public static Map<Person, Double> totalScores(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
        Map<Person, List<Integer>> scores = results
                .flatMap(cr -> cr.getTaskResults().entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getValue() >= 0)
                        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(cr.getPerson(), e.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(e -> Optional.ofNullable(e.getValue()).orElse(0), Collectors.toList())));


        Map<Person, Double> averageScores = new HashMap<>();
        scores.forEach((person, taskResults) -> {
            int totalScore = taskResults.stream()
                    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                    .sum();
            double tasksPerPerson = scores.get(person).stream()
                    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                    .filter(score -> score >= 0)
                    .count();

            double averageScore = totalScore / tasksPerPerson;
            averageScores.put(person, averageScore);
        });
        return averageScores;
    }
```

Comment: when you're saying something goes wrong once 0 appears, could you specify what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I think you tried to explain, but I am sorry, it still isn’t clear to me exactly what your code is supposed to do and whether it should treat a score of 0 differently. A [mre] would also help so we can run your code and see for ourselves.

Comment: I mean that if Student have a some number (in my case is 4) of laboratory works, some of which Student passed (in my case is 3) for some points, and some (1) not (they should become 0 points), and then the totalScore should count average values including tasks that a Student did not try to solve (with 0 score), but it count without 0 points.
And averageTotalScore should calculate the average values for each lab, including all Students (in my case is 3) and those who did not try to solve (with 0 points).

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. Please when supplying such additional explanation (or any other information), do it as edits to the question so that we have everything in one place, it’s much nicer. This time I pasted it in there for you (only this time).

Comment: So if a student only has got 3 task results, how should your program be able to guess that there had been supposed to be 4?

Comment: I made some changes to clarify details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding a filter for 0 value check should fix the issue, something similar to below:

```
public Map<Person, Double> totalScores(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return results.collect(Collectors.toMap(CourseResult::getPerson, result -> result
            .getTaskResults()
            .values()
            .stream().mapToInt(s -> s).filter(value -> value != 0)
            .average()
            .orElse(0.0)));
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work (

Comment: I believe the OP wants 0s counted in the averaging, which this would end up excluding them.